# iOS5: A UIPopover/Sliptview issue after upgrade to iOS5 in xcode

Tags: ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, xcode4.2

After updating my iPad and xcode to the lastest versions iOS5 and xcode 4.2 when I run my application on the ipad, in landscape view the splitscreen works as it should, where as when I then rotat it to portrait view then press the button/menu icon I get the popover but no content just the top of the popover comes up. See image attached

[image: Popover in portrait view]

The menu button is generate via code not and a normal button see below:

```
   -(void)viewMenu:(id)sender{

      [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame 
                        inView:self.view
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                        animated:YES];
      [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(10.0f, 50.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
  }
```

The menu list is populated via a plist code.

a little more splitview code is as follows:

```
   - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController *)pc
   {
       barButtonItem.title = @"Menu";
       self.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:254.0/255.0 green:193.0/255.0 blue:32.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
       self.toolbar.hidden = YES;
       NSMutableArray *items = [[self.toolbar items] mutableCopy];
       [items insertObject:barButtonItem atIndex:0];
       [self.toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
       [items release];
       self.popoverController = pc;
        viewMenu.hidden = NO;
   }

   // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
   - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
   {
       NSMutableArray *items = [[self.toolbar items] mutableCopy];
       [items removeObjectAtIndex:0];
       [self.toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
       [items release];
       self.popoverController = nil;
        viewMenu.hidden = YES;

   }
```

Any ideas whays going on and how I can correct this issue?

Comment: In viewMenu, why is presentPopoverFromRect called twice?  The second call looks like the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment below my question and the rest of over night my issue was caused by duplicated code which for the life of me after staring at code all day I could not see.

Many Thanks to Anna Karenina for the observation, shame I cannot vote for  a comment.

The duplicated code and the one that I need to remove was in the first lot above and the correct code after removing the duplication is show below.

```
   -(void)viewMenu:(id)sender{
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(10.0f, 50.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    }
```

thanks again